# Is there an example of a bounded connected set that is not Jordan measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Like the title asks, is there an example of a set that is connected and bounded that is not Jordan measurable?

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R^2$, consider $([0,1] \times \{0\}) \cup (E \times [0,1])$ where $E \subset [0,1]$ and $E \times [0,1]$ is not Jordan measurable.

Comment: Where $E\subset [0,1]$ I presume?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (I'll edit).

Comment: What is E in the example?

Comment: Would $([0,1]\times\{0\})\cup(\Bbb Q\times[0,1])$ work? It's closure isn't of the Jordan measure $0$ and that would be a union of densly located parallel stripes connected by $[0,1]\times\{0\},$ right?